# Como substituir uma Imagem por um Texto?

Tags: vb.net, imagem

Estou a desenvolver um projecto no qual necessito substituir uma imagem por um certo texto, quando a mesma não está a carregar.

**Exemplo:** Caso a imagem não carregue, mostre uma mensagem informando que não foi possível obter a imagem. Isto é possível? A minha imagem está a surgir dentro de uma `RichTextBox`, em conjunto com texto.

Comment: Neste caso você quer algo que seja feito diretamente com VB.net ou essa verificação pode ser em JavaScript por exemplo?

Comment: Preferencialmente seria algo para fazer no código VB.net, mas se houver uma solução em Javascript que me permita colocar o código em funcionamento, também servirá

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta para o meu problema, no stack overflow em inglês.
Este caso funcionou para o que eu precisava: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12136321/3206532)

Se não quiserem navegar até ao link, aqui fica o pedaço de código:

```
    Dim input As String = "test<img>" ' your data here
    Dim imgRegex As New Regex("<img[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim output As String = imgRegex.Replace(input, "")
```